# How to Change Month Format of Fill Series in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have months in my column header and I want Excel to Fill them in sequentially.  It currently does this by default but it is filling in the long month even though it understands my short month.

Eg:  I manually wrote in 'Sep' for September but it fills 'October' in the next column instead of 'Oct.'

I know Excel has both versions of months stored in it's default Custom Lists.  How do I get it to switch?

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1003278/how-to-return-the-three-letter-month-abbreviation-of-a-date-in-excel-2010) out.

Comment: Write 2 consecutive cells select it and drag

Comment: @yass - (At least in Excel 2016) you just need to type "January" and can drag that right or down to fill in the other months. Just noting, I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: yes in most Excel you can but maybe he has other months written at the same row

Comment: I can't reproduce in Excel 2007. You can clear the cell's formats, or change them to General

Comment: @yass.  your 2 consecutive cells suggestion works!  I had VBA code programmed to fill one cell from past month to current month.  I told it to start with JAN and it worked fine until I got to 'MAY.'  Excel got confused bc this stupid month is the same in long and short version.

Comment: I thought you had something in the sheet that prevented the autofill

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula :

```
=Text(A1,"mmm")
```

Where `A1` is the cell/column/row, thus u can change it to your requirements.
After typing that formula drag it along the following rows and it will apply the formula accordingly.

Also for further refrence and/or questions u may also check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1003278/how-to-return-the-three-letter-month-abbreviation-of-a-date-in-excel-2010).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Formula in VBA to fill the rest of the months:

```
[A1] = "May"
[B1:L1].Formula = "=TEXT((A1 & "" 1"") + 50, ""mmm"")"
[B1:L1] = [B1:L1].Value2                      ' optional to convert the formulas to values
```